# iOS App localization Crash on language change

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, crash, xcode6

I have localized my app with storyboards. It has the following behavior:

> Works fine when built to device in development language (English)
>
> When I change the iPhone language to something that the app is localized in, and open the app, it shows a black screen for a short amount of time (1-5 seconds) before crashing.
>
> With the phone now in another language, if I build the app to the phone, it works fine and loads the localized storyboards.

So, to restate: this localized app refuses to open when the language is changed, but works fine if I then build it to to the device again from XCode.

What is going on? iOS bug, or do I have something configured wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find out why and how to fix it ?

Comment: @karlml No solution yet... but I have found a workaround of re-installing/re-building the app to the device after the language has been changed, which works in my experience.

Comment: Yes, but what about the end user? I think there must be something going on with the dateFormatter not updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. And I checked all Localazation files in storyboard , and it works fine to me. Like below image.
[image]

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Can you elaborate what you mean by "I tried to set all languages files the same in storyboard Localization" ?